# Delete selected key and value after it had been serialized to array by jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, serialization

I used `serialize()` jQuery function and it will catch all value by name of the selected form, like the code bellow.

```js
$('#serialize').click(function(){
    var ser = $('#form1').serialize();
    alert(ser);
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <form id="form1">
    <input type="text" name="text1">
    <input type="text" name="text2">
    </form>
    <button id="serialize">Serialize</button>
```

**Result**

```
text1=&text2=
```

Is there a way to delete the `text1` just after it serialize ?

**The Result I expect**

```
text2=
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than removing it after the fact, try to filter it before serializing it, for example:

```
$("#form1").find("input[name!=text1]").serialize();
```

This example will find find all of the inputs within form1 that doesn't have the name of text1, then it will serialize that.

Comment: What  if i have 2 filter ? is that possible ?

Comment: did i have to .find().find() ?

Comment: If you want to filter 2, you just keep chaining the find() function. Like this $("#form1").find("input[name!=text1]").find("input[name!=text2]").serialize();

Comment: make sense, i have upvoted this but maybe i will wait for another answer. But for now i can do this trick for my problem. thanks @GaryMathis !

Comment: I've never tried this within the find() but you can try to pass multiple selectors to a single find. Kind of like $("#form1").find("input[name!=text1], input[name!=text2]").serialize(); I don't know if that would work in the scenario.

Answer (score 2):

An approach, that would let you have a data structure with the ignored form element names, would be this:

```
// Object with the names of the form elements to ignore
var filters = {
    "text1": true,
    "textN": true
};
$("#form1")
    .find(":input")
    .filter(function (i, item) {
        return !filters[item.name];
    })
    .serialize();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove from serialize by making element to `disabled`

```js
$('#serialize').click(function(){
    removeParam("#form1 [name=text1]");
    var ser = $('#form1').serialize();
    console.log(ser);
});

function removeParam(p) {
    $(p).attr("disabled",true);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <form id="form1">
    <input type="text" name="text1">
    <input type="text" name="text2">
    </form>
    <button id="serialize">Serialize</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to exclude multiple values as per your comment in the accepted answer Here is the solution that works best.

```
$("#form1:input[name!=text1][name!=text2]").serialize();
```